# How to combine 2 Javascript functions into one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function, which I want to re-use as an "action" template and pass another function as a parameter, which will be the **action function, to be executed in the middle of it.**

**QUESTION**

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Note that the "action" is asynchronous and also I'm using React.

```
  function templateAction(action) {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      setError(null);

      // DO SOMETHING
      action();

      setLoading(false);
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      setError(err);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

And inside that `action()` call should execute the following function:

```
  async function getBlogPost() {
    const querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('blog').where('slug','==',props.match.params.slug).get();
      console.log(querySnapshot.docs);
      if (querySnapshot.docs.length === 0) {
        throw 'ERROR: BlogPost not found...';
      } else if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 1) {
        throw 'ERROR: More than 1 blogPost found...';
      }

      const blogPostData = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();

      setFirestoreID(querySnapshot.docs[0].id);
      setBlogPost(blogPostData);
  }
```

**SNIPPET**

I think that I've built the behavior that I need (run snippet). Can I do it simpler than that? It seems a lot of boilerplate.

```js
async function templateAction(action) {
  try {
    console.log('Template Action BEFORE calling action');
    await action();
    console.log('Template Action AFTER calling action');
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function action() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
    console.log('I am sync from action function BEFORE async call');
    await mockAPI();
    console.log('I am sync from action function AFTER async call');
    resolve();
  });
}

function mockAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('I am from async mockAPI call');
      resolve();
    },1500);
  });
}

templateAction(action);
```

Comment: change templateaction to an async function and copy the body of the getBlog post where you want it go. that said, it's usually a better idea to keep many smaller functions than few large ones.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've edited because it wasn't really clear. I mean the I want that other function to be executed in that point. That `action()` call should execute the function that was passed as parameter. And I want to make it reusable to use with other `actions` other than `getBlogPost`

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. but I want to keep them separate so I can reuse the `templateAction`, otherwise I'll need that same boilerplate for every `action` like `getBlogPost`

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think I'm close. I'm still testing what happens with the async calls. I think I'll need to make the `template` async and make the `action` return a promise.

Comment: I'll edit soon with a snippet with simpler functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final code, with error catching using try catch blocks.

It works, though I think it hurts readability.

```js
async function templateAction(action) {
  try {
    console.log('Template Action BEFORE calling action');
    await action();
    console.log('Template Action AFTER calling action');
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log('I was caught and logged');
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function action() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
    try {
      console.log('I am sync from action function BEFORE async call');
      await mockAPI();
      console.log('I am sync from action function AFTER async call');
      resolve();
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log('I was caught');
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}

function mockAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('I am from async mockAPI call');
      resolve();
    },1500);
  });
}

templateAction(action);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass by anonymous function like this: https://codesandbox.io/embed/awesome-mayer-52ix7

```
function templateAction(action) {
  action();
}

let test = function() {
  alert("test");
};

templateAction(test);
```

For the async part, maybe you will need to make promise, depending if you need a confirmation for the action.
With reactJS you can make this more simple by using scope sending properties and getting using "this.props"

Comment: With promise will be something like https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dream-jl1xg?from-embed